# What is the difference between dispatch_time and dispatch_walltime and in what situations is better to use one or the other?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I know that `dispatch_time` is the time according to device clock and if the device goes to sleep the clock sleeps too. On the other hand the `dipatch_walltime` is time according to wall clock, which never goes to sleep. My questions is, is there any difference, performance-wise or other, to use one or the other in different situations? Can somebody give me some more details, because the Apple docs are not exhaustive.

For example I'm writing a `Timer` class which operates on certain intervals. Also the leeway could be 10 to 30 secs. Which one should I use `dispatch_time` or `dispatch_walltime`, performance-wise.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`dispatch_time` stops running when your computer goes to sleep. 
`dispatch_walltime` continues running because the real world continues running.

So suppose you want to do an action 1 hour from now, but after 5 minutes your computer goes to sleep for 50 minutes. Then:

- `dispatch_walltime` will execute an hour from now, 5 minutes after the computer wakes up.
- `dispatch_time` will execute after the computer is running for an hour, that is 55 minutes after it wakes up, 1 hour and 50 minutes from now.

Comment: What about time jumps?  When daylight saving is setting back 1 hour?